# Optimizing the selection process

Tags: mobile, android, ios, users

I am developing a mobile application in which the user selects the fields that s/he wants to enter information into. At the moment, I have two screens - one for selecting the fields and other for entering the information.

My goal is to choose a design that is very intuitive and minimizes the number of screens/views that the user has to visit. With that in mind, please suggest a way so that I can allow the user to accomplish selection of fields and data entry on just one screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with two screens is that if user will change his mind he will have to go back to select/unselect the items. It's better to place everything on the one single screen and allow user to input values instantly. For example, you may try to use a well-known pattern (used in address books, etc) of choosing a type of a field and entering value inplace:

[image: inplace]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the user directly choose which fields to enter (the application doesn't need to make any decisions about what needs to be filled), I suggest simply allowing the user to leave fields they decide not to enter blank.

Comment: thanks for your response. I had considered this approach, but the problem is if s/he wants to modify a field, the user has to scroll through the entire table to find the fields that have info.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that with one screen it's possible to condense the table any further.

Since being able select a field to modify requires displaying the field **at least somewhere**, fitting everything in one screen will require listing all modifiable fields in that screen.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the text "optional" in a distinguishing color just to the left or above  each field's title.

If a user sees 8 fields with 6 of them clearly optional upon a quick glance of the page, that won't feel like a page with 8 fields.

Still, work VERY hard to trim down to the fewest fields needed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Another route is to have just the few basic fields and add an "advanced" button which leads to a page with more fields.